# why focusout missing selected option(s)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusout, focusin

i'm using jquery focusin and focusout for expand and minimize a multiple option select on a form:

```
$("#orgns").focusin(function() 
{ $(this).attr({'size':10}); })
 .focusout(function() 
{ $(this).attr({'size':1}); });
```

every thing is ok, and 1 line dropdown expands when it's get focus, one or more options is select, and then move to next filed on form. but when return back on drop down and focus on it again the previous selected option is missed. any idea please.

Comment: Do you do something with the selection when it's selected ? They might be something removing the seleted option from the list

Comment: absolutly no. it's confuse me. i replace focusin and focusout by hover event & it's working charm. by the way i want to use focusin and out.